# ERROR: PostGIS is already installed in schema 'public', uninstall it first

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.2

None of the threads in stack exchange related to this error helped me to resolve this issue. Hence I am posting it.

I have installed postgres 9.3 and PostGIS 2.1 
Now I have done the following

```
su postgres
createuser -U postgres gis
createdb -U postgres -E UTF8 -O gis gis
createlang -U postgres plpgsql gis

psql -U postgres -d gis -f /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
psql -U postgres -d gis -f /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

Now when I try to create extension for postgis with the following

```
psql --username=postgres --dbname=gis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

I get this:

```
ERROR:  PostGIS is already installed in schema 'public', uninstall it first


gis=# \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public | spatial_ref_sys | table | postgres
(1 row)

gis=#
```

This is the table

I tried altering the db with search path as well but no luck  `ALTER DATABASE gis SET search_path = postgis;`

This is the list of my dbs

```
gis=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 gis       | gis      | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

gis=#
```

Comment: In version 2.x you needn't to execute sql scripts (e.g. spatial_ref_sys.sql and postgis.sql). Drop and recreate your database and use `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` instead of executing sql scripts.